# Set TextWrapping Property to ComboBox Item (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

How can i set textwrapping= wrap to the items of combobox item. Can I use 
`ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle` or do I have to edit the Control Template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourDisplayProperty}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```